Get the size of all PostgreSQL DB
I would like to know all the sizes of all the PostgreSQL DB running on a particular system.
For example, in a system I have installed PostgreSQL and created multiple databases(mydb_1, mydb_2, mydb_3...mydb_N) in that.
SELECT pg_database_size('db_name');

The above only giving me size of the specific db passed in the sql as parameter.
Is it possible to get the sizes of all the databases in the system using single SQL statement.

Since you can get the list of database names from pg_database, you can try:
select datname, pg_database_size(datname) from pg_database;


Thank you its working fine.
select datname as db_name, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) as db_usage from pg_database;

@subhasis - if you are happy with an an answer, please mark it as correct!
